# How to transform Flow<List<T>> to Flow<T> in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I get a flow of type `Flow<List<T>>` and I need to get a flow of type `Flow<T>` out of it.

I tried:

```
outerFlow.onEach { items -> items.onEach { flow { emit(it) } }
```

This does not work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-concat.html) for `flatMapConcat`:

```
outerFlow.flatMapConcat { it.asFlow() }
```